# How do I write an iterative code for a single-lined pattern?

Tags: python, string, algorithm, for-loop, iteration

I would like to seek help in writing an iterative code for a pattern, which would pass the following test cases as follows:

```
pattern(1) gives *-

pattern(4) gives *-*--*---*----

pattern(6) gives *-*--*---*----*-----*------
```

I tried writing like this but it gives me *- *- *- *- instead

```
def pattern(number):
    result = "#-"
    for i in range(1,number):
            result += "#-"
    return result
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
def pattern(number):
    result = "*-"
    for i in range(1,number):
            result += "*" + "-"*(i+1)
    return result
```

This gives:

```
>>> pattern(1)
'*-'
>>> pattern(4)
'*-*--*---*----'
>>> pattern(6)
'*-*--*---*----*-----*------'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! How did u come up with result += "*" + "-"*(i+1)?

Comment: The website that u provided is useful for my learning. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 3):

You don't exactly even need a full for loop for this. You can use `str.join` and a simple comprehension

```
def pattern(number):
    return '*'.join('-' * n for n in range(number+1))

>>> pattern(1)
*-
>>> pattern(4)
*-*--*---*----
>>> pattern(6)
*-*--*---*----*-----*------
```

Comment: I would use the `itertools` module instead of `map` here. `'*'.join(repeat("-", i) for i in range(1, number + 1))`.

Comment: Or that generator is fine, too :)

Comment: That was an interesting way of solving for this code though I have not learnt how to use the join function yet. Thanks all for your help tho! :)